# how to get value from model pop up in telerik web?

Tags: asp.net

My Question IS :

I Have one web form on this web form I have one check box and when I check the checkbox at that time to open model pop up and some value entre in text box and get back value on main form.?

Help

Answer (score 0):

The model popup is actual part of the page. You only show/hide it with JavaScript

Beside that all controls on that dialog are part of the same form that are posted back on the same page.